# Failed to decode downloaded font - Angular2

Tags: css, angular, fonts, sass, font-face

I'm having this issue with reading custom fonts in angular2, after deploying to the server, it has errors with decoding. Take a look at the screenshot.

[image: issue]

This is fonts.scss

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Decalotype';
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url('./assets/fonts/Decalotype-Light.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('./assets/fonts/Decalotype-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('./assets/fonts/Decalotype-Light.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('./assets/fonts/Decalotype-Light.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('./assets/fonts/Decalotype-Light.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('./assets/fonts/Decalotype-Light.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```